# Dynamically Generate Ids for jQuery Fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, mako

I am trying to integrate a calender view in a python based application. I Am almost done with it. now i have only a single problem of generating Ids for the calendar fields. eg If I have one calendar field then that field works fine with the below code, however if I have 2 or more calendar fields in one form how would I generate Ids for Them. and is there a need to write a separate script for every field. here is my code sample that I apply for a single field.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {
            $('#popupDatepicker').calendarsPicker({calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'), dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});

        });
</script>
```

And My web application code is here :-

```
 <input type="text" **id="popupDatepicker"** name="${name}" autocomplete="OFF" size="3"
class="${css_class}" ${py.attrs(attrs, kind=kind, value=value)}/>
```

Now I want to generate **id** dynamically. The above code is called nly on my calendar type of fields. so how should i generate `<input Ids >` and their respective script here.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't assign a class to all the calendars and then just call `$('.calendar').calendarsPicker(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead give them a *class* of popupDatepicker, and then change your jQuery to use `.popupDatepicker` instead of `#popupDatepicker`.

So replace your HTML with the following:

```
<input type="text" class="popupDatepicker" name="${name}" autocomplete="OFF" size="3" class="${css_class}" ${py.attrs(attrs, kind=kind, value=value)}/>
```

And your jQuery with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $('.popupDatepicker').calendarsPicker({calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'), dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not make a class only for those fields you want to have calendar then edit your selector as:

```
 //get the element with popupDatepickerClass class and makeit a calendarsPicker()
 $('.popupDatepickerClass').calendarsPicker(SOME TXTS);
```

notice how your '#' becomes '.'

your element looks like:

```
 //add the popupDatepickerClass on every element you want to be converted as calendar
 class="${css_class} popupDatepickerClass"
```

this way your script will look for all elements with the same class and make it a calendar.

```
 //create a css class with name: popupDatepickerClass and its not necessarily to have a value
 .popupDatepickerClass { }
```

Comment: I am not much prone to css and Javascript. Can U xplain me with the above code

Comment: i added some comments for you to understand what in the code. its already readable.